# Why does removeItem have the function added, but when the method is called, it returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, closures

```
function Coll(items) {
    this.removeItem = items.pop
}
const coll = new Coll([2,4,6,8,10])
console.log(coll.removeItem())
```

If I make `console.log(coll)`, I can see that there's a function inside of the object. If I call it, it retuns undefined. I know the solution to make it run properly is to add
`() => items.pop()` but I still can't understand why. The main question here is what happens when I add the `() => ...()` to the method call

Comment: For the same reason `const f = item.pop; f();` doesn't work -- it doesn't set the value of `this` to the right thing when calling `pop`. See the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)'s answers. Probably your best bet is `this.removeItem = () => items.pop();` but you could also use `bind` as the answers there show. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: The reason is that you're losing context. Imagine that `Array.prototype.pop` calls `this.length` in order to know the array length and know what item to remove when calling `pop()`.

Having: `var items = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];`
Calling `items.pop();` makes the context (`this`) be the caller (`items`);

`this.length = items.length`; -

But if you only store the function reference, you will lose the context: `var a = items.pop; a()`;

Unless, you create a new function with the context bound:
`var a = items.pop.bind(items); a()`;